# Bind mount not working for postgresdb in Docker Desktop

Tags: docker, docker-compose, windows-10, microservices, docker-desktop

I am facing issue in bind mount in docker desktop for windows and error is resolved by creating volumes, but i have to use bind mounts or please tell me how to access the volumes in windows 10. Please help.

Here is my compose file:

```
services:
    postgresdb:
        image: postgres:10.14-alpine
        container_name: postgresdb
        restart: always
        environment:
          - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123456
        #   - PGDATA=/postgresql/data
        volumes:    
            - ./data/postgresdb:/var/lib/postgresql/data
            - ./db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
        ports:
            - "5432:5432"
```

Error in container logs:

> PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping
> initialization
>
> 2020-10-16 13:20:30.944 UTC [1] FATAL: data directory
> "/var/lib/postgresql/data" has group or world access
>
> 2020-10-16 13:20:30.944 UTC [1] DETAIL: Permissions should be u=rwx
> (0700).

Comment: Not sure what the config and the error message have to do with bind mounts, you may want to clarify your question a bit. The error message should be somewhat self-explanatory - the permissions on that directory are too lax, here's something about docker volumes and permissions: https://medium.com/@nielssj/docker-volumes-and-file-system-permissions-772c1aee23ca

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am running 8 different containers and sharing bind mount inside containers and all are working fine except one "postgresdb" in windows 10 pro. and i also test this on windows 10 home and everything is working fine there.